# Check integer base representation

Tags: python

I define an integer like this:

```
x = 0xFF
```

But when i ask for its value to the interpreter i get:

```
255
```

Is there a way to force the interpreter to return me the value the same way I defined it? 
Is there a way to check the base representation for an integer?

Comment: "force the interpreter to return me the value the same way i defined it"?  What does this mean?  Does this mean `x=2+2` should report `2+2` instead of `4`?

Comment: It means that if you enter 0xFF, it should return 0xFF when you ask for its value. I mean, if you define a variable whose value is represented in base-16 (hexadecimal), the interpreter should show it represented in the same base, and not in base-10 as it does.

Comment: What is the difference between `0xff`, `255` and `128+127`?  I don't see how you can tell these apart?  What is the rule?

Comment: From an arithmetical point of view, there is no difference. I just want my program to show the result of a function (which is an integer) with the same representation the value i received as an argument had.

Comment: "with the same representation"?  Still confuses me.  What if I write `2+0x3` What is the "same" representation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway the value will be represented in binary. 
Python doesn't remember the way you wrote the value when you decided to assign it to a variable.
If you want to store this information create a specific class that will store this information for you and display the value correctly. Note that when you will be assigning the value you will have to specify the base explicitly anyhow.

Answer (score 4):

**No.** Neither Python nor any other language I know stores the base you write an integer literal in. `0xFF` is indistinguishable from `255`. These are both converted to the same underlying representation: binary.

- If you want to remember a base then you need a different type than `int`. Perhaps store the integers in string form `"0xFF"`, or as a tuple `(0xFF, 16)`. `int` simply doesn't have the information you want.
- More realistically, it is your responsibility to format output the way you want. If you feed a hexadecimal number into a function and get a result back, it's your job to format the result as hexadecimal as well. I would not expect this code to "do what you want":

  ```
  print foobar(10)
  print foobar(0xFF)
  ```

  Make your intentions explicit. If the default formatting (decimal) isn't to your liking then override it:

  ```
  print '%04d' % (foobar(10)))
  print '%04x' % (foobar(0xff)))
  ```

Answer (score 2):

0x is hex.

To force the interpreter to show the original value:

```
hex(x)

>>> x = 0xFFF
>>> x
4095
>>> hex(x)
'0xfff'
>>>
```

Comment: But i may not know the base the number is represented in advance.

Comment: I could have binaries, decimal, octal, or hexadecimal.

Comment: There is no difference between these. This is the same number. If you do a `type(x)` on the above, it will still return an int. Why do you want to know whether that is hex or octal? The number is the same.

Answer (score 1):

0xFF (hex) and 255 (decimal) are the same number. So are 0377 (octal) and 11111111 (binary). Whatever base you define it in, it's the same underlying value, and it no longer matters how you declared it.

Comment: Of course, they are the same number. What i'm asking is if there is a way to get the base a number is being represented.

Comment: For example, something like: base(0xFF) ---> return 16

Comment: No. Python doesn't care how you defined it. 0xFF is just binary 11111111 and Python will print it as '255' unless you say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The integer is represented using the standard integer representation (base 2). When you define the integer you assign it a value which is implicitly converted from your representation, so the original base is lost. If you wanted you could define your own class which stores this information along with the underlying integer value

Answer (score 0):

What everyone else says above is true - 0xff is the same as 255 decimal. If you need to be able to maintain the string representation for some other purpose, you can do something like this:

```
class VerboseInt(object):
   def __init__(self, val):
      '''
         pass in a string containing an integer value -- we'll detect whether
         it's hex (0x), binary (0x), octal (0), or decimal and be able to
         display it that way later...
      '''
      self.base = 10
      if val.startswith('0x'):
         self.base = 16
      elif val.startswith('0b'):
         self.base = 2
      elif val.startswith('0'):
         self.base = 8
      self.value = int(val, self.base)         

   def __str__(self):
      ''' convert our value into a string that's in the same base
      representation that we were initialized with.
      '''
      formats = { 10 : ("", "{0}"), 
            2: ("0b", "{0:b}"), 
            8: ("0", "{0:o}"), 
            16: ("0x", "{0:x}")
            }

      fmt = formats[self.base]
      return fmt[0] + fmt[1].format(self.value)

   def __repr__(self):
      return str(self)

   def __int__(self):
      ''' get our value as an integer'''
      return self.value
```

Answer (score 0):

What would you expect from:

```
 x = 0x7F + 128
 print x
```

The numeric base is not part of Python's internal representation of an integer. You could, if you wanted, maintain a string instead of an int, and explicitly convert to int when you needed to.